# Flutter & Google Sign-In: Web Client ID works for Android, Android Client ID does not work for Android

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-signin

So this is definitely a puzzler to me. I'm building a Flutter application and using the newest version of [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) (6.1.0 at the time of this post).

I've set it all up as what I think is appropriate, and when I try and login, I get the ubiquitous error message:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:
```

I know that usually this has to do with ensuring that your application is properly registered in Firebase and the SHA-1 key matches and whatnot. Part of my problem is that I'm not using Firebase, I'm using Identity Platform, so it's a little different. This is also a new problem that has recently come up, because previously it's worked. Generally my setup goes like this:

1. APIs & Services -> Oauth consent screen, go through and complete all of the required fields and whatnot.
2. APIs & Services -> Credentials

   - Create 2 Oauth 2.0 Client IDs
   - First is for Web, with Authorized Origins & Redirects
   - Second is for Android, Package name matches my AndroidManifest file, SHA-1 matches my android debug keystore
   - Note: there is also a third Client, "Web client (auto created by Google Service)"
3. Identify Platform -> Providers, add Google

   - Under the Web Client ID & Secret, I put the "Web client (auto created by Google Service)" ClientID and Secret.
   - Under Allowed client IDs, I include both the Android ClientID and the Web ClientID that I created
   - I save all of the above
4. In my application, when I run it for web, it logs in without issue.
5. When I change nothing about it except to run it on Android and use the Android ClientID, it throws the above error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:
```

However, if on Android, again changing nothing else, except I use the Web Client ID instead of the Android Client ID, it works fine, no issues.

Does this make sense? Should it be acting like this? I feel like I'm missing something. Any input is helpful.

Comment: You can enable Authentication service and enable Email/Password & Google as sign in methods to do it properly and you also will need to add SHA-1 key compulsorily.

Comment: I agree, but I did all of that prior to doing the above. Well, I enabled Google login instead of Email/Password, and I had already added the SHA-1 key (and rechecked it, so I know I was in the correct place). And it still behaved as the above.

Comment: Try one thing, completely remove your project from firebase and then try to add new project again and this time you enter the SHA-1 key at initial step only and then enable Google login as well as Email/Password both and also delete old auth key and generate new one after doing all of these steps.